# Why does 'yield' yield twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code:

```
def bootstrap_form_field(f, method, text, &block)
  content_tag :div, :class => div_classes(f, method) do
    f.label(method.to_sym, text) +
    content_tag(:div, :class => "input") do
      concat(yield + error_display(f.object, method))
    end
  end
end
```

which I'm expecting to produce something like this:

```
<div class="clearfix error">
  <label for="xlInput">X-Large Input</label>
  <div class="input">
    <input class="xlarge error" id="xlInput" name="xlInput" size="30" type="text">
    <span class="help-inline">Small snippet of help text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

from a call such as:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_field f, :password, "Password" do %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
<% end -%>
```

but my yield, appears to be yielding twice:

```
<div class="clearfix error">
  <label for="user_password">Password</label>
  <div class="input">
    <input id="user_password" name="user[password]" size="30" type="password">
    <input id="user_password" name="user[password]" size="30" type="password">
    <span class="help-inline">can't be blank</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

How so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  def bootstrap_form_field(f, method, text, &block)
    content_tag :div do
      f.label(method.to_sym, text) +
        content_tag(:div, :class => "input") do
          yield + error_display(f.object, method)
        end
    end
  end
```

should work. There is no need for concat but I don't remember why.

EDIT:

See https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4d3ec4c6a8584fdd9275576ecab07302973e7cc5/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb#L51 I think concat is the right way to add a string to output buffer in helper. So, it's normal to get text twice time with

```
concat(yield)
```

Comment: I edited the question. It should work but I can't test it because I don't have that method ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= bootstrap_form_field f, :password, "Password" do %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
<% end -%>
```

=>

```
<% bootstrap_form_field f, :password, "Password" do %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
<% end -%>
```

Comment: That seems to result in no output at all.

Comment: This answer helped me - I believe it's down to the return value of the helper when you keep the `=`. If you yield the block without explicitly returning `nil`, you can get a duplicate. I.E. `return yield block unless condition` duplicated the block, while `unless condition; yield block; return nil; end` fixed this for me - still keeping the `<%= %>` syntax. Hope that makes sense / can help someone!